# Java - How many objects of objects can you have?

Tags: java, arrays, object, generics, linked-list

So I have a linked list which hold User objects:

(USLinkedList is the name of the linked list data structure I've created)

(Users is a class I've created)

```
      private USLinkedList<User> users;
```

I want an array to hold objects of these linked lists:

```
      private USLinkedList<User> dates[];
```

I want another array to hold objects of the the above array:

```
      private USLinkedList<User> dates[] months[];
```

I finally want this array to go in a linked list:

```
      private USLinkedList<USLinkedList<User> dates[] months[]> years;
```

I want to know:

- if something like this is even possible?
- if it is possible, is my syntax correct, i.e. is my code correct?
- is it good programming practice to do something like this?

Thanks guys!

Comment: Having complex structures of arrays is usually a good sign that you want to encapsulate something within an object and just have a list of that object.

Comment: That's a fair point, I'll try something like that.

Comment: Your syntax is not correct. `USLinkedList<User> dates[] months[];` and `USLinkedList<USLinkedList<User> dates[] months[]> ` didn't throw compiler errors at you?

Comment: What is the correct syntax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, no, maybe, in that order.

*Can you do it?*  You can have collections of collections to whatever depth you require.

*Is the syntax right?*  The syntax is not as you depict.  This bleeds into the "good practice" discussion, but mixing lists and arrays as you have seems arbitrary and will likely lead to confusing syntax.  Certainly your access patterns might justify having some levels be organized as linked lists and others as arrays, but there are `List` implementations for both of those and I would advise using them for consistency.  So the examples I show will be the correct syntax for that.

*Is it good practice?*  There are several aspects to this.

The data structure itself?  Well, if you need the data structure organized in this way then that's what you need.  If something simpler would intuitively meet the requirements, then it's bad practice; but if this is the simple, intuitive way to do what you need to do, then it's fine.

The `USLinkedList` implementation is a bit of a question mark for me.  Perhaps it does something that the provided List implementations can't do; but if so, it's not obvious from what you've said.  If a `java.util.LinkedList<User>` would work, then using it would be a better practice than reinventing the wheel.  Even if you do need your own `USLinkedList` for whatever reason, if possible it should implement the `List` interface and preferably references should address it as a `List`.

And as noted above, I wouldn't mix arrays and lists without a very good reason.  `LinkedList` and `ArrayList` (or `Vector`, depending on synchronization needs) should work fine and allow you to consistently use the `List` interface.

*So back to the syntax...*:

I suggest using interface types for references and I suggest using generics.  So you have

```
private List<User> users;
```

which you can populate with

```
users = new LinkedList<User>();
```

(If you really need the custom list implementation, you can replace `LinkedList<User>` with `USLinkedList<User>` throughout.  And if it can't implement the `List` interface, then you can also replace `List<User>` with `USLilnkedList.)

Next up the line,

```
private List<List<User>> dates;

dates = new ArrayList<List<User>>();
dates.add(new LinkeList<User>()); // or whatever...
```

Then

```
private List<List<List<User>>> months;

months = new ArrayList<List<List<User>>>();
//etc.
```

and

```
private List<List<List<List<User>>>> years;
// well, you get the idea, right?
```

But again, all this assumes that there's a solid reason for this multi-level indexing.  You can, and if it really is the straightforward way to do what you need that's fine... but I have to say I can't remember when I've last needed such a nested structure.

Comment: Thank you, I think this is by far the best response! The point is we had to make our own data structures, so we couldn't use any of java's preexisting data structures.

Comment: But I think I'll make more objects and just store those objects in the final linked list.

Comment: Do not use `java.util.Vector`, which has been obsolete for nearly 19 years.

Comment: @LewBloch - Funny, the JavaDoc doesn't say it's deprecated.  And in fact in Java 1.2 (19 years ago) they specifically retrofit Vector to the Collections API.  And much later still, they added generic support.  That doesn't seem like what you do to indicate that something is considered obsolete.  Do you have a source (i.e. one that is somehow more authoritative than the JavaDoc), or is this merely your opinion?

Comment: @MarkAdelsberger Vector’s synchronization is on a per-element level and therefore is almost never useful.  It probably is not deprecated because so many early APIs depend on it.  As for sources, a quick search turned up https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A97688_16/generic.903/bp/java.htm#1007005 and https://blogs.oracle.com/geertjan/entry/oh_no_vector .

Comment: @VGR - Actually, deprecated is *exactly* what you do if you don't want people to keep using something but can't do away with it for backward compatibility. (You then start weeding it out, which Sun and then Oracle could easily easily have done in 20 years if they'd wanted.) So your reasoning makes no sense. The first link recommends using Vector only if you need its synchronization model - which is exactly what I said above only more emphatic in that it suggests that you probably don't need it.  The 2nd link is a blog, which is hardly an authoritative source.  Nice try, though.

Comment: If Vector were deprecated, developers could not use, for instance, [this DefaultTableModel constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html#DefaultTableModel-java.util.Vector-java.util.Vector-) without seeing a deprecation warning.  So, no, Vector cannot reasonably be deprecated, because there are older APIs which require it.

Comment: @VGR - Wrong again.  First, that's what SuppressWarnings is for.  Second, as I noted above, if there were any initiative to remove Vector from the API it would be done by now.  Any claim that it's "obsolete" is baseless opinion unless/until Oracle deprecates it.

Comment: @Mark Adelsberger, funny, I didn't say it was deprecated either.

Comment: @Mark Adelsberger Is Oracle.com authoritative enough? https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A97688_16/generic.903/bp/java.htm#1007192

Comment: @LewBloch - Repeating a source I already responded to, but with less context this time?  Clearly you're desperate to be right, so I'm done talking to you about it.

Comment: I recommend listening to Oracle. And let's also apply logic. `Vector` contains more than we need, like `Enumeration`. Other `List` implementations do not, It's a well-established best practice to use the simplest implementation for your needs. Every other `List` implementation provides synchronized methods if wrapped in a `synchronizedList` call; `Vector` only supports a poor man's `ArrayList`. So `Vector` provides unwanted cruft and has a direct replacement that doesn't, and is more versatile. Simple engineering reasoning dictates the abandonment of `Vector`.

Answer (score 0):

`private USLinkedList<User> dates[] months[];
 private USLinkedList<USLinkedList<User> dates[] months[]> years;`

The syntax in both cases are not correct, and even if was, this is just confusing.

Java is an oop language, oop is used to make things more simple for us humans.

I think the right way will be to create an object Dates which holds `private USLinkedList<User> dates[];`
and then create an object of MonthDates which holds `private USLinkedList<Dates> month;`

and then create another object of FullDates which holds `private USLinkedList<MonthDates> fullDates;`

I know it means you should create 3 new objects but this way it much more simple and easy to understand, also the syntax is correct  ¯_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: I think most people - myself included - would argue that these extra objects are *less* simple if the exist only to contain a List (which, after all, is already itself an object)

Comment: Yes, there are people who would disagree,
of course I made each list as an object just for the example.
Also the fact that `private USLinkedList<Dates> month;` is an object now, can help you if you wish to override the sort method or somthing like that.

I hope the point I am trying to show is clear...